# Draw a circle in ArcGIS map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have Center point(Latitude,longitude) for a place and radius. How to draw a circle/polygon on an ArcGIS map using Latlong and radius(also need WKT string).
I am new to ArcGIS & do not have much idea about ArcGIS.

Comment: are you limited to c#? if you interest with arcpy(python) i can give you an example...

Comment: Thank you so much for your immediate reply.Basically i am C# programmer.Please share me your code and steps how do we implement this in ArcGIS.

Comment: but my code will be in python hovewer you want?

Answer (score 4):

Yes finally i got it...

I am sharing it here.I hope my code will help someone.

```
 Private void DrawCircle()
{
 _pointAndBufferGraphicsLayer = esriMap.Layers["Graphics Layer"] as GraphicsLayer;  
  Symbol _activeSymbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["DefaultFillSymbol"] as Symbol;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polygon polygon=new Polygon();
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection pointCollection = 
  new  ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection();
  polygon.SpatialReference = esriMap.SpatialReference;
  double radius=0.6;
  MapPoint pp = new MapPoint(55.00206, 24.98167); //Lat long;
  var PointCount = 40; // number of points on the circle
  var angle = 360 / PointCount; // used to compute points on the circle
  for (var i = 1; i <= PointCount; i++)
       {
           // convert angle to raidans
           //var radians = i * angle * Math.PI / 180;
           double radians = 2 * Math.PI / PointCount * i;
           // add point to the circle
           double x = (pp.X + radius * Math.Cos(radians));
           double y = (pp.Y + radius * Math.Sin(radians));
           pointCollection.Add(new MapPoint(x, y));
       }
        polygon.Rings.Add(pointCollection);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic gr = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic() { 
        Geometry =polygon, Symbol = _activeSymbol };
       _pointAndBufferGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(gr);//If already have graphics layer
       // esriMap.Layers.Add(_pointAndBufferGraphicsLayer); //If not already have graphics layer
            esriMap.ZoomTo(polygon);
    }
```

Thanks to all for your help.

NOTE:  this loop is measurably faster if you calculate `2 * Math.PI / PointCount` just once, outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you: [How to efficiently create a polygon](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/9df45774-c95a-4ae4-9a0d-3eedcf58c5c0.htm)

Comment: Here also i cant find the solution....